# Waffle vote counter

Tags: script, bookmarklet, fun

It is my firm belief that every +10 vote after reaching the repcap can be redeemed for free waffles{*}.

I often hit the cap on MSO, and I like to see how many waffles SE Inc owes me. So I have a bookmarklet that does the job--it adds up wafflevotes for every day on a page.

```
 javascript:$(".grid-rep-header").each(function(){a=$(this).parents("table").find(".grid-rep-col1");var b=0;var c=0;for(var d=0;d<a.length;d++){if(($(a[d]).parent().children(".grid-rep-col3").children("span").html().indexOf("upvoted")!=-1||$(a[d]).parent().children(".grid-rep-col3").children("span").html().indexOf("downvoted")!=-1)&&!$(a[d]).children("span").html().match(/\d/)){htm=$(a[d]).parent().children(".grid-rep-col4").children("a").attr("href");factor=$(a[d]).parent().children(".grid-rep-col3").children("span").html().indexOf("upvoted")==-1?0:1;factor=$(a[d]).parent().children(".grid-rep-col3").children("span").html().indexOf("downvoted")==-1?factor:-1;if(htm.indexOf("#")==-1){b+=factor*.5}else{b+=factor}}repChange=parseInt($(a[d]).children("span").html(),10);c+=isNaN(repChange)?0:repChange}$(this).html($(this).html()+" Rep: "+c+" Waffle: "+b+"("+b*10+" rep)")})
```

To install, copy the above into a bookmark in your bookmark bar.

To use, open the rep page in **mobile view** and click the bookmarklet.

Just a bit of fun :)

[image]

<sup>* See [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/128351/178438) and [footnote here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/129944/178438)</sup>

Comment: Awaffly wonderful.